# Can I determine only what data has changed in a subscription in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

So I have a meteor collection full of GPS coordinates which I plot on a map. Anytime data changes in my Meteor collection, I have a deps.autorun that clears all the markers that aren't in my subscription. Then I draw all the markers that have yet to be drawn. If I have a bunch of data that updates quickly, the browser on my iPhone crashes. So I would like to be able to be able to update the map for only what has changed, rather than scanning each time and finding what has changed to lighten the load. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: are you already using [observeChanges](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes)?  This seems like the right place to look at both what is added and what is removed.  Even this might not be necessary depending on how your templates are organized around the subscription data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user728291 is right, [observeChanges](http://docs.meteor.com/#observeChanges) or just [observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) is used in such situations.

What you want to do is to track all new objects by ids:

```
Template.map.rendered = function () {
  Places.find().observe({
    added: function (doc) {
      // code to add pin of doc
    },
    changed: function (newDoc, oldDoc) {
      // code to move pin from oldDoc position to newDoc
    },
    removed: function (doc) {
      // code to remove a pin associated with doc
    }
  });
}
```

In fact, whenever you combine `{{#each things}}...{{/each}}` template helper with your data returned as MongoDB cursor:

```
Template.myTemplate.things = function () {
  return Things.find({ rating: { $gt: 3 } });
}
```

Meteor will do the same thing under the hood. UI system will observe the changes on the cursor an instead of redrawing everything, it will figure out what changed and update only relevant parts of your displayed list.

Comment: Interesting. So observe completely replaces the need for Deps.autorun in this case. :)